# How to add a parameter to URL in all ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, backbone.js

I have a Backbone application using jQuery and want to append a `sessionId` parameter to the URL of all ajax calls?

How can I do this in Backbone or jQuery, maybe in a global way and without rewriting the Backbone.Sync?

So if I have url `www.example.com/users`, I want that to become `www.example.com/users?sessionId=12314q234123412`

Comment: We are using cookie, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [advanced options of `jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#advanced-options). In your case, you should register a global [prefilter](http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/#Prefilters) to modify the sent `data`. Watch out to do this only on request to your own domain, otherwise that could be a security leakage.

Another option would be to create a simple wrapper function that extends the options passed in:

```
 function myAjax(options) {
     options.url = "mydomain";
     options.data = $.extend(options.data||{}, {sessionID: 12345});
     return $.ajax(options);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the global [`.ajaxSend()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) event.